# Nodejs app not working with crontab @reboot

Tags: node.js, linux, cron

T'm trying to run a nodejs program after system reboot, I'm using crontab @reboot to do this but it did not work.
Here is my config steps, any idea what's wrong?

1. I'm using aws linux, and installed nodejs by nvm;
2. which node
   `/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.3/bin/node`
3. my test.js located
   `/home/ec2-user/spider/logger.js`
4. this works fine
   `/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.3/bin/node /home/ec2-user/spider/logger.js`
5. this also works fine
   `@reboot echo "hi" > /home/reboot.txt 2>&1`
6. crontab -e
   `@reboot /root/.nvm/versions/node/v7.1.0/bin/node /home/user/test.js`
7. reboot, test.js never gets run

Also tried :
`* * * * * /root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.3/bin/node /home/ec2-user/spider/logger.js >> /home/crontab.log 2>&1

* * * * * echo $(date '+%Y %b %d %H:%M') >> /home/reboot.txt 2>&1

* * * * * echo "hi" >> /home/hi.txt 2>&1`
**Only last one worked.**

Comment: Does it work when you put a time in the crontab? like `11 12 * * * `?

Comment: @daniel  - did you ever solve this?

Answer (score -2):

The crontab syntax composed of two parts, datetime to execute & command to be executed. In this case, you command is `/root/.nvm/versions/node/v7.1.0/bin/node /home/user/test.js`

```
*     *     *   *    *        command to be executed
-     -     -   -    -
|     |     |   |    |
|     |     |   |    +----- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0)
|     |     |   +------- month (1 - 12)
|     |     +--------- day of        month (1 - 31)
|     +----------- hour (0 - 23)
+------------- min (0 - 59)
```

Comment: This is a good explanation of how cron works, but it does not answer the question